# Prolog - How to calculate the total number of elements

Tags: prolog

How do you calculate the total number of elements in a list when there can be lists within a list? (add the length of all the lists together)

```
?- sumOfLists([[1,2],[],[a,s,d],[a,1,3],[1]],S).
    S = 9
```

Comment: recursively find the lengths of all sublists and add them?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the shorter way I know, using [flatten](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=flatten/2)/2:

```
sumOfLists(Ls, S) :-
  flatten(Ls, Flat),
  length(Flat, S).
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without flattening and without using maplist.

Here is my proposal:

```
%element atomic? -> count
deep_len([H|T],N) :- atomic(H), deep_len(T, M), N is M + 1.

%element list? -> recurse for head and tail and sum results
deep_len([H|T],N) :- is_list(H), deep_len(H, Sum1), deep_len(T, Sum2), N is Sum1+Sum2.
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `maplist` to replace each list by it's length, then sum up the lengths.

Using a `sum` predicate like this one:

```
sum(L, S) :- sum(L, S, 0).
sum([], Acc, Acc).
sum([X|Xs], Sum, Acc) :- 
  Acc1 is Acc + X, 
  sum(Xs, Sum, Acc1).
```

it boils down to just:

```
sumOfLists(L, S) :- maplist(length, L, Lengths), sum(Lengths, S).
```